# Exclude pattern in python output

Tags: python, regex

I'm scraping a .txt file in python, and I'm using regex to capture ticket numbers and names:

```
for line in Text:
    if re.match('Ticket:|Name:', line):
        print(line)
```

Based on my .txt file, this is capturing the correct fields as well as my blank lines (not yet filled out):

```
Ticket:  123
Name:  Person123
Ticket:  124
Name:  Person124
Ticket:  
Name:  
Ticket:  
Name:
Ticket:  
Name:
```

If I append a `\n` to my regex it'll print my blank lines, but is there a way to keep my "filled out" lines and also exclude the blanks with their line break?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following code will skip empty lines by adding **\s+** which Matches Unicode whitespace characters (which includes `[\t\n\r\f\v]`) one or more time then adding **\w+** which Matches Unicode word characters one or more; this includes most characters that can be part of a word in any language, as well as numbers and the underscore. If the ASCII flag is used, only `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` is matched

```
for line in Text:
   if re.match('Ticket:\s+\w+|Name:\s+\w+', line):
        print(line)
```

output:

```
Ticket:  123
Name:  Person123
Ticket:  124
Name:  Person124
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use [rstrip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) and specify a newline `\n`

```
for line in Text:
    if re.match('Ticket:|Name:', line):
        print(line.rstrip('\n'))
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/HXZ75200)